# Mouse flickering on triple monitor setup in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, mouse, amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome

I recently added a new Radeon Cedar video card to my machine for a third monitor and whenever I have the third monitor enabled I get an obnoxious mouse flicker. The most prevalent offender is web browsers, especially when a page is loading or I'm scrolling the page. But, I also encounter it to a limited degree in programs like Sublime 3 and Gnome Terminal. The odd thing is the flicker is limited to the window of the program. If I mouse to a different program, it's fine.

I suspect a driver issue, but I'm not sure how to identify or solve that problem. I've looked through google and all the similar bug reports seem to be years old and either resolved with a comment saying a fix was pushed or not at all.

OS: Ubuntu Gnome 16.04
VC: Radeon Cedar

Comment: I'm seeing this issue, as well, three monitors, 16.04, all Acer AL2216Ws, with an Nvidia GeForce 8200 and 210. I've tested KDE, Gnome, and Unity, and they all work (kinda). KDE provides the best non-flickering, but it's so different compared to Unity that I'm not sure I like it. Gnome worked for a bit, with less flicker, but then crashed... Surprised there is not a workaround or patch for this yet... The original bug report was filed quite a while ago.